# Issue with WatchService in java 7

Tags: java-7, watchservice

I'm using jdk7's WatchService API for monitoring the folder on file system.I'm sending a new file through 
email to that folder, when the file comes into that folder i m triggering the ENTRY_CRATE option. its working fine.
But the issue is its generating two events of ENTRY_CREATE instead of one event  which i'm invoking.

BELOW IS THE CODE:

```
Path dir =  Paths.get(/var/mail);
WatchService watcher = dir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();       

dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);        
System.out.println("waiting for new file");
WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take(); 
List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
System.out.println(events.size());              

for(WatchEvent<?> event : events){  
    if(event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE){ 
        String fileCreated=event.context().toString().trim();
    }
}
```

In the above code I'm gettng the events size as 2.

Can  any one please help me in finding out the reason why i'm getting two events.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that there might be some temporary files being created in the folder at the same time. Just check what are the name/paths of the file being created.